# BS doesn't "see" all tables?

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse through data on baseball-reference.com and it works find for every page, except for a few like [this one](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201205030.shtml) Same pages (different data) work perfectly, ie [this one](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/MIN/MIN201204120.shtml).
I'm trying to filter out tables with 'stats_table' as one of the classes. I use this code:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(stream, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('table'))
```

and then I do sth like:

```
for table in bs.find_all('table'):
     print table.attrs
       ... bla bla...
```

It is obvious out of table.attrs that this code doesn't see batting and pitching tables and that they are there... I repeat: the same code works fine for almost all other pages like this.
Looking over str(bs) clearly shows that

ANY ideas?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by batting tables. Which ones aren't you seeing exactly, I'm seeing `TorontoBlueJaysbatting` and others?

Comment: Yes, that's right... None of the two are detected, as are not pitching ones as well. I now opened the page in firebug and it seems to have bugs... Any ideas on how to automatically fix them? Stray head end tag seems to be the problem but I don't see how to fix it exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you posted in the comments there are errors on the page. You should use HTML Tidy to clean it up : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytidylib/0.2.1

You can check HTML Tidy at work: http://validator.w3.org/